# Acquiring aggregate total : How do I aquire the aggregate total of female/ male by province by sexual or physical from this Code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I aquire the aggregate total of female/ male by province by sexual or physical from this Code?

```
SELECT sv.province_name, sv.district_name,
          sum(sexual_female_less_10) as sexual_female_less_10,
          sum(sexual_female_10_14) as sexual_female_10_14,
          sum(sexual_female_15_19) as sexual_female_15_19,
          sum(sexual_female_20_24) as sexual_female_20_24,
          sum(sexual_female_25_plus) as sexual_female_25_plus,
          sum(sexual_male_less_10) as sexual_male_less_10,
          sum(sexual_male_10_14) as sexual_male_10_14,
          sum(sexual_male_15_19) as sexual_male_15_19,
          sum(sexual_male_20_24) as sexual_male_20_24,
          sum(sexual_male_25_plus) as sexual_male_25_plus,
          sum(physical_female_less_10) as physical_female_less_10,
          sum(physical_female_10_14) as physical_female_10_14,
          sum(physical_female_15_19) as physical_female_15_19,
          sum(physical_female_20_24) as physical_female_20_24,
          sum(physical_female_25_plus) as physical_female_25_plus,
          sum(physical_male_less_10) as physical_male_less_10,
          sum(physical_male_10_14) as physical_male_10_14,
          sum(physical_male_15_19) as physical_male_15_19,
          sum(physical_male_20_24) as physical_male_20_24,
          sum(physical_male_25_plus) as physical_male_25_plus

   FROM vw_experiencedphysicalviolence pv
   JOIN vw_experiencedsexualviolence sv ON pv.id = sv.id
   GROUP BY sv.district_name, sv.province_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the OVER clause.

i.e.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sv.province_name,
    sv.district_name,
    sum(sexual_female_less_10) OVER (partition by sv.province_name, sv.district_name) as District_sexual_female_less_10,
    sum(sexual_female_less_10) OVER (partition by sv.province_name) as Province_sexual_female_less_10,
...
FROM vw_experiencedphysicalviolence pv
JOIN vw_experiencedsexualviolence sv ON pv.id = sv.id
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: And if OP is not using SQL Server?

Comment: PostgreSQL, MySQL, DB2, Prestodb (Amazon Athena), Redshift, and Oracle all support windowing functions (aka analytic queries in Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of details.

1. In your `GROUP BY` clause, you are grouping on district and province.  In your question, you specify province.  If that is correct, your group by should look like this `GROUP BY sv.province_name`
2. When posting SQL questions, it helps to tag with the database engine you are using.  In this case, the answer is likely covered by the ANSI Standard.  However, more advanced queries will likely rely on vendor specific SQL implementations.
3. If you want to aggregate the total number of males and females by province, then you sum the columns and sum the aggregates together.

See sample code below:

```
SELECT 
sv.province_name, 
sv.district_name, -- Remove if you remove from group by clause
sum(sexual_female_less_10) +
sum(sexual_female_10_14) +,
sum(sexual_female_15_19) +
sum(sexual_female_20_24) +
sum(sexual_female_25_plus) AS total_f_sexual_violence,  
sum(physical_female_less_10) +
sum(physical_female_10_14) +
sum(physical_female_15_19) +
sum(physical_female_20_24) +
sum(physical_female_25_plus) AS total_f_physical_violence,  
sum(sexual_male_less_10) +
sum(sexual_male_10_14) +
sum(sexual_male_15_19) +
sum(sexual_male_20_24) +
sum(sexual_male_25_plus) AS total_m_sexual_violence,
sum(physical_male_less_10) +
sum(physical_male_10_14) +
sum(physical_male_15_19) +
sum(physical_male_20_24) +
sum(physical_male_25_plus) AS total_f_physical_violence
FROM vw_experiencedphysicalviolence pv
JOIN vw_experiencedsexualviolence sv ON pv.id = sv.id
GROUP BY 
sv.district_name, -- Per your question you may not want to group by district_name  
sv.province_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. The Reason I am grouping by district and province is because I want to be able to filter by district and province. I am using Apache superset (Postgres SQL) to run this query.